# how to make sure two random numbers are not the same in javascript

Tags: reactjs, random, setinterval

I am learning React and Javascript, I am writing a small app that have 40 squares with different colors and every second 2 colors will randomly change, everything works fine but I have one minor problem. How can I change my code so that if two numbers are the same one of them will be regenerated? I tried to use if like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const totalColor=40;
const Box=(props)=>{...}

class RandomColorApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);   
        const boxes = new Array(totalColor).fill().map(this.randomColor,this);
        this.state={boxes}

        setInterval(()=>{

           const randomIndex1=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
           const randomIndex2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
           if(randomIndex1!==randomIndex2){
              console.log(randomIndex1,randomIndex2)
           }
        },1000);
    }

    randomColor(){...}
    render(){...}

}

RandomColorApp.defaultProps={colors:[...]}

ReactDom.render(<RandomColorApp/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

but the problem is, the whole process will be delayed by 1 second before it regenerates new numbers, and also is there a way I can refactor the code so I do not have to repeat Math.floor(Math.random()*3) too much in case I need more than 2 random numbers, thank you verymuch

below is my full code just in case it can help

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

const totalColor=4;
const Box=(props)=>{
    const style={
        width: '180px',
        height: '180px',
        display: 'inline-block',
        backgroundColor: props.color
    }
    return <div style={style}/>
}

class RandomColorApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);   
        const boxes = new Array(totalColor).fill().map(this.randomColor,this);
        this.state={boxes}
        setInterval(()=>{
            const boxes=this.state.boxes.slice();
            const randomIndex1= Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length);
            const randomIndex2= Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length);
            boxes[randomIndex1]=this.randomColor();
            boxes[randomIndex2]=this.randomColor();
            this.setState({boxes});
            //const randomIndex1=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
            //const randomIndex2=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
            //if(randomIndex1!==randomIndex2){
            //    console.log(randomIndex1,randomIndex2)
            //}
        },1000);    

    }

    randomColor(){
        let colorIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*this.props.colors.length)
        return this.props.colors[colorIndex];
    }

    render(){
        const boxes=this.state.boxes.map((color,index)=>(
            <Box key={index} color={color}/>
        ))
        return(
            <div className='RandomColorApp'>
               {boxes}
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

RandomColorApp.defaultProps={...}

ReactDom.render(<RandomColorApp/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a setInterval() in the constructor?

Comment: where else should you suggest me to put it?I will give you my full code after I have the answer, everything runs automatically and there is no onSubmit form as well as onClick function

Comment: Got it. Added an answer. Hope it will address your question.

Answer (score 3):

First define below function to generate a random number in the given range which is not equal to the `except` value.

```
randomNumber  = (max, min, except) => {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min +1)) + min;
    return (num === except) ? randomNumber(max, min, except) : num;
}
```

After that use below code in your setInterval() method

```
const randomIndex1 = randomNumber(0, totalColor, -1);
const randomIndex2 = randomNumber(0, totalColor, randomIndex1)
```

In this case, `randomIndex1` will never be equal to `randomIndex2`

Comment: I will check it the first thing tomorrow. Thank you vey much. Also do you know how to refactor it? Just in case I want to have like 10 or 20 random numbers that change color at the same time

Comment: what happens if min==max==except?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry in that case it would go on an infinite loop. But I assume in this case min != max for all scenarios.

Comment: @nhat this solution works, but only for 2 selections from the range.  If you want more, the "except" value would need to be the current list of selections, and the code would need to check all of them... This would degrade sharply the closer the number of selections you want gets to the size of the range.  i.e. if you wanted 25 numbers from 1-40, this would be a slow solution.

Comment: @nhat an alternative for large numbers of selections would be to create an array containing all the values (1-40 in this case), then shuffle it randomly, then slice off the number of selections you want.

Comment: @billjamesdev that could 
Work. Ill try it soon thanks

Comment: @Nhat I have an answer below that does it.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of distinct numbers, you can use an array and shuffle it:

```js
a=new Array(10).fill(1);
a=a.map((x,i)=>i);
a=a.sort(()=>{return 2*Math.random()-1});
for (let i=0;i<a.length;i++) console.log(a[i]);
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in the topic. I mean I have an array with 40 different colors and I want to extract 2 random numbers out of the array. But 2 random numbers must be different. Sorry for any confusion I am still learning. I can get two random numbers from the length of the array but sometime two random numbers generate the same number

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this function will take a rangeMin, rangeMax, and selectionCount, and return an array containing selectionCount unique values from the range.  It will not validate that Min != max, etc.  This is efficient for non-large values of (rangeMax - rangeMin), and is much more efficient than random selection and testing when selectionCount is a non-trivial portion of (rangeMax - rangeMin).

```js
var getSelections = function( rangeMin, rangeMax, selectionCount ) {
// make array containing all values possible
var arr=Array.from({length: (rangeMax-rangeMin)+1 }, (v, k) => k+rangeMin);
arr=arr.sort(()=>{return 2*Math.random()-1}); // shuffle the array
return arr.slice( 0, selectionCount );
}

var values = getSelections( 1, 40, 2 );
console.log( "2 values from 1-40" );
console.log( values );

var morevalues = getSelections( 1, 8, 5 );
console.log( "5 values from 1-8" );
console.log( morevalues );
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
//declare an array to add the numbers
let myArr = [];

//loop through the array to add up to 6 numbers ()
while (myArr.length < 6){

//assign random number to a variable
let random = Math.floor(Math.random()* 25) + 1;

//check if the number assigned to the variable exist in myArr[]
if(myArr.indexOf(random) > -1) {
    console.log('Matching number ' + random + ', getting a new one');
    //if number exist don't push the number and go back to the head of while loop
    continue;
}

//if number doesn't exist push it to end of myArr[]
myArr.push(random);
}

console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: Answers should not solely consist of code, but also explain what the code does and why it solves the problem. Please read [answer] for more information